# Draggabke works only once when applied to two different divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an Image and a or a  tag with some text added between them using input box.
I want to make both the text and the image draggable. However drag works only once on text. The image can be dragged and dropped for as many time as i want but text can be dragged only once. Can you please find out the main problem.

Jquery

```
$(function() {
    $('#uploadedPhoto').draggable({
        containment: '#dragDiv'
    });
});


$(function() {
        $('.customText').draggable({
            containment: '#dragDiv'
        });
});
```

CSS

```
.customText {
    position:absolute;
    cursor:move;
    font-size: 3em;
}
#uploadedPhoto {
    display:none;
    position:relative;
    cursor:move;
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    left: 2.5em;
    opacity:0.70;
    }
```

Jquery versions (links in html file)

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks

Comment: what jquery and jquery UI version are you using?

Comment: @Edward i have edited the post above to include everything about Jquery versions

Answer (score 1):

You are including jQUery twice (with different version) which may cause weird problem.

Try take out:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your uploadphoto has a property of `display: none;` That means it is not rendered and till then it cannot be made draggable. So remove this property - `display: none;` from `#uploadedPhoto` and try again.

Comment: The property is changed as soon as it is uploaded. The draggable works fine with #uploadedPhoto it doesn't work with .customText.